# How can I copy the following excel data into a different workbook and have it prompt the user to save?

Tags: excel, vba

**Essentially I have the following code stating what cells I would like to copy over into another workbook:**

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
ActiveSheet.Copy
Range("A1:T40").Copy

Range("A1:T40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

The VBA script automatically opens a new workbook with all of the data pasted from the other workbook.

But now I would also like it to prompt the user with a save window as soon as the new workbook opens, how can this be done?

**UPDATE:**

**The following code prompts the user to save the excel workbook, what can I add to have it save to a specific file with a specific name?**

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
 fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx*),*.xlsx*")
If fileSaveName <> False Then
 MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName

End If
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String


Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
ActiveSheet.Copy
Range("A2:T40").Copy

Range("A2:T40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True



path = "C:\Users\jmills\Documents\Report\"

filename1 = Range("H1")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

How can I keep the save as prompt up? I would like it to allow me to edit the name before it saves

Currently with the code above it saves automatically with whatever is written in cell H1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the save filename dialog with `Application.SaveAsFileName`. Here is more info on what you can do with it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename

The output of this is a path were you can save the workbook to.
So afterwards, you need to use something like `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=[output from application.saveasfilename]`

Like this:

```
path = "C:\Users\jmills\Documents\Report\"
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( initialFilename:=path & "myworkbook", _
 fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx*),*.xlsx*")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Where you can change `myworkbook` to whatever you want. The user can change that as well in the filedialog if they want.

Comment: Right but the issue is I don't know what file name excel will make for the new workbook it copies the cell data to, so I can't really trigger the dialog on this new workbook it creates

Comment: You choose the filename in the saveasfilename dialog. This dialog doesn't really save your file, but only returns a string. You can save your file with `.SaveAs`.

Comment: Please have a look at my update, I really appreciate it

Comment: fileSaveName now contains the path to where you want to save the file (unless they cancel in which case it's `false`). Assuming that the new file is now the active workbook, you can use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName`

Comment: But I would like to make a custom file name, like "MyWorkbook" instead of what it auto generates

Comment: You want to choose your own filename,right? That's what the saveasfilename dialog is for. Maybe it's pre-filled, but you can change that if you want.

Comment: I understand, but what I would like to be pre-filled with a custom name

Comment: Check the link in my answer, you can fill in the `initialFilename` attribute.

Comment: Please have a look at my update, I think I am very close, I would just like the save as screen to stay and wait for me to press save instead of doing automatically

Comment: Check my edit. I just combined your code. I haven't tested it though so check for typo's etc.

Comment: The code is executed but the initial filename is not shown

Comment: Can you try without ".xlsx"?

Comment: Got it to work, the issue was the extension (.xlsx) in the initial filename